# Can't access to a Docusign action json node in an omniscript

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

The Docusign action is in the json node everytime the user click on the action, so i'm trying to reference the status of the action to add a validation but I can't access to the json node.
This is the json node:

```
{
   "DS_SignatureAction":[
      {
         "status":"In Process",
         "envelopeId":"a079a5ef-ae6d-4a6f-9483-583a881e826a"
      },
      {
         "status":"Completed",
         "envelopeId":"2e679aed-bc09-4cbf-830b-2b16cb1eb28b"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I tried with:

```
%DS_SignatureAction|1:status%, %DS_SignatureAction:status%, %DS_SignatureAction%
```

But no one of these work, so anyone know if it is a bug or what is happening? Thanks

Comment: My name is Gloriana and I'm part of DocuSign's Developer Support team. Can you please provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve, for example what endpoint are you hitting and exactly what are you looking for? It may be best to open a case at https://support.docusign.com/.

Comment: Hi Gloriana, I tryied to open a case in docusign since yesterday but it says that the Login failed and I need to wait for 30 minutes, so anyways I can explain you from here. We are trying to put a validation to make sure that the user sign the document before he can go on, but for some reason we don't have access to the docusign action json node, the formula that reference that json node always it's null. And we figured out that if the omniscript is desactivated, the formula gets populated correctly (it works fine) but if it is active the formula always will be null. Thank you!

Comment: HI Nahuel, please try to open a case with DocuSign customer support to review this issue as we may need additional specific information for this issue. Thank you.